# Reshape two string columns to make count inbetween in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns and I want to reshape the table for a cross-count. How may I achieve this through Pandas?

```
data = {
    "fruits": ["orange, apple, banana", "orange, apple, banana", 
               "apple, banana", "orange, apple, banana", "others"],
    "places": ["New York, London, Boston", "New York, Manchester", 
               "Tokyo", "Hong Kong, Boston", "London"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                   fruits                    places
0   orange, apple, banana  New York, London, Boston
1   orange, apple, banana      New York, Manchester
2           apple, banana                     Tokyo
3   orange, apple, banana         Hong Kong, Boston
4                  others                    London
```

Expected output:

```
      New York  London  Boston  Hong Kong   Manchester  Tokyo
orange  2          2       2        1            1        0
apple   2          1       2        1            1        1
banana  2          1       2        1            1        1
others  0          1       0        0            0        0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) on the splitted/exploded columns:

```
df2 = (df.apply(lambda c: c.str.split(', ')) # split all columns
         .explode('fruit').explode('places') # explode to new rows
       )
pd.crosstab(df2['fruit'], df2['places'])     # compute crosstab
```

output:

```
places  Boston  Hong Kong  London  Manchester  New York  Tokyo
fruit                                                         
apple        2          1       1           1         2      1
banana       2          1       1           1         2      1
orange       2          1       1           1         2      0
others       0          0       1           0         0      0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's procede by steps:

```py
df2 = df.copy()
df2["fruits"] = df["fruits"].str.split(", ")
df2["places"] = df["places"].str.split(", ")
df2
```

[image: out1]

```py
df3 = df2.explode("fruits").explode("places")
df3.head()
```

[image: out2]

```py
pd.pivot_table(df3, index="fruits", columns="places", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
# Or, using crosstab: 
# pd.crosstab(df3["fruits"], df3["places"])
```

[image: out3]

It is left as an exercise to the reader to bring all those steps together :)

Comment: lol for ending with __left as an exercise to the reader__

Comment: A quick question @Thrastylon - what's the difference on using pivot_table vs crosstab? I like your approach because everything is a bit explicit but I am just curious if I might miss out something.

Comment: I usually go with `pd.pivot_table` because it allows me to learn only one function I fully understand. It also operates on a dataframe (as opposed to arbitrary series for crosstab) which I found prevented me from some silly mistakes. At the end of the day it's only a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return pd.crosstab(dd.fruits,dd.places)
df.applymap(lambda x:x.split(',')).explode(column=['fruits', 'places']).pipe(function1)

places    Boston   London   Manchester  Hong Kong  London  New York  Tokyo
fruits                                                                    
 apple         0        1            0          0       0         0      0
 banana        2        0            1          0       0         0      0
apple          0        0            0          1       0         1      0
banana         0        0            0          0       0         0      1
orange         0        0            0          0       0         1      0
others         0        0            0          0       1         0      0
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to create cartesian product using `itertools.product` and then use `pd.Series.explode` and `pd.crosstab`

```
from itertools import product
f = lambda x: list(product(x['places'].split(','), x['fruit'].split(',')))
df['fruit_places'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
ddf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['fruit_places'].explode().values, columns=['places', 'fruit'])


 pd.crosstab(ddf['fruit'], ddf['places'])
```